# I can't upgrade ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 because of a dropbox upgrading problem

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dropbox

I tried to upgrade dropbox after having received a pop-up message in desktop from dropbox asking me to do it. I followed the instructions on the dropbox official downloading page. Dropbox can now only be accessed trought the command `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` and it seems that my cpu is overused. When I restart my computer, dropbox still asks me to upgrade. I tried again but I had the same results again and adain

I currently use ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits). I tried to upgrade to 14.04, but the upgrading process is eventually blocked on downloading dropbox and nothing happens

Comment: Try to uninstall everything dropbox-related, then try to upgrade to 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The upgrades blocked on downloading dropbox. I opened a terminal and killed the dropbox update proces (usr/bin/python /usr/bin/dropbox update). Doing so made the upgrade continue.

I will probably have to upgrade dropbox manually after the kubuntu upgrade has finished.

Comment: This looks like a fine answer. Could you add on how to kill the dropbox update process?

Comment: Rogier's reply was helpful. To kill the process try `ps -a | grep nautilus-drop` (I think it is called `nautilus-dropbo` or sth) and then `sudo kill -9 <pid>` where pid is the process id number.